# Bluetooth headset starts lagging after some time of inactivity

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio, bluetooth, bluez

I recently bought a Samsung Level U bluetooth headset and succesfully connected it to my computer.

I use Arch Linux and followed the [tutorial in Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#Configuration_via_CLI) to connect it. It uses A2DP profile and works fine for a while but when I - say paused a video and wait for a while - and continue playing the video, both video and sound lags and I have to basically power off/on my headset or disconnect via `bluetoothctl` and reconnect.

Sometimes if I try to disconnect and immediately reconnect via `bluetoothctl` it gives a `bluez.error` and fails.

```
Some info:
Arch Linux
pulseaudio  11.1
bluez       5.47
```

I can provide configuration files alas I don't know which ones are relevant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some BT adapters has a bug in suspend mode. My solution for Asus BT400:

Find vendor and product id:

```
$ lsusb | grep Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0b05:17cb ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Broadcom BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
```

In this example vendor id is `0b05` and product id is `17cb`.

Create file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-bluetooth.rules` with your ids from previous step:

```
# Bluetooth devices.

# Asus BT400 bluetooth adapter.
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0b05", ATTR{idProduct}=="17cb", ATTR{power/autosuspend}="0"
```

Set mode to 644:

```
chmod 644 /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-bluetooth.rules
```

Reconnect your adapter or change attribute manualy by:

```
echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/YOUR/DEVICE/power/autosuspend
```

Enjoy!

Some useful info commands:

```
udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/bus/usb/BUS_ID/DEVICE_ID)
udevadm test '//devices/DEVICE_PATH'
```